# How to change CakePHP validation error message

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.3

I have read the CakePHP documentation about validation rules, but I'm still stuck with changing the error message on an email field.

I currently have this Validation rule in my model:

```
public $validate = array(
    'emailadres' => array(
        'rule'       => 'email',
        'required'   => true,
        'allowEmpty' => false,
        'message'    => 'My custom error message'
    )
);
```

The field shows up as being mandatory, but a standard error message appears instead of my custom message.

Does anybody see what I'm doing wrong?

My CakePHP version is 2.3.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to double check the documentation: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/data-validation.html#one-rule-per-field

Its not `'ruleName'   => 'email',`, but `'rule'   => 'email',`.

You can also try the verbose representation:

```
public $validate = array(
    'emailadres' => array(
        'email' => array(
            'rule'       => 'email',
            'required'   => true,
            'allowEmpty' => false,
            'message'    => 'My custom error message'
        )
    )
);
```

Comment: ... and `emailadres` (with single `d` and single `s`) suggests a typo.

Comment: Sure does. I would also spell it "emailaddress" or even "email_address".

Comment: Emailadres is Dutch notation. This represents the database field. The problem still exists though...

Comment: Try the verbose array structure at http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/data-validation.html#multiple-rules-per-field - even if its just a single field, this representation is future proof, and should work.

Comment: Even with your example the message hasn't changed. See [link](http://dev4.west-dyke.com/verhuur/reserveren)

Comment: Haha, thats HTML5 validation ;) Has nothing do to with PHP, its frontend sugar from the browser itself.

Comment: That has been introduced in 2.3 - see http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/appendices/2-3-migration-guide.html#formhelper